# Fullpage.js. How to disable delay between normalizing elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

Pacient: http://demo.imatte.us/fomru/landingpage.html

Problem: http://gyazo.com/031fe1c5413550e6e68aceef2740cefc

When window's size is changing, then we can see content of other slide. But after release the window's border, elements moving to right places with animation after small delay. How to disable this delay and animation, and force elements to stay on right positions constantly?

Comment: the delay is to keep the resize functionality from running on every window.resize event (throttling). It could potentially slow your app significantly by removing said delay. You'll have to edit the source of fullpage.js

Comment: Can't find what I should to edit in fullpage.js

Comment: I'd recommend trying a solution before posting. I found it in a minute. line 1050 of the latest version. Once again. I don't recommend this.

Answer (score 1):

As @flybear pointed out, you would need to modify the plugin for it.

You would also need to change the `scrollingSpeed` of the plugin by using `$.fn.fullpage.setScrollingSpeed(0)`. But this will only work if you use `css3:false`.

You should change the current event `resize` for this one:

```
//when resizing the site, we adjust the heights of the sections, slimScroll...
$(window).resize(function () {
    // rebuild immediately on touch devices
    if (isTouchDevice) {
        $.fn.fullpage.reBuild();
    } else {
        $.fn.fullpage.setScrollingSpeed(0);
        $.fn.fullpage.reBuild();
        $.fn.fullpage.setScrollingSpeed(700); //default one
    }
});
```

If you want to make it work with `css3:true` as well, you would need to deal with the `css3` animations defined in the `.fp-easings` class. You probably can create another CSS class to overwrite the `.fp-easings` one defining a `transition` with `0` seconds:

```
//when resizing the site, we adjust the heights of the sections, slimScroll...
$(window).resize(function () {
    // rebuild immediately on touch devices
    if (isTouchDevice) {
        $.fn.fullpage.reBuild();
    } else {
        $.fn.fullpage.setScrollingSpeed(0);
        $('.fp-easings').addClass('.fp-no-transitions');
        $.fn.fullpage.reBuild();
        $.fn.fullpage.setScrollingSpeed(700); //default one
        $('.fp-easings').removeClass('.fp-no-transitions');
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.fp-no-easing {
    -webkit-transition: all 0s ease-out !important; 
    transition: all 0s ease-out !important;
}
```

Just take into account that on every resize event, which can be fired hundreds of times when you resize the browser's window, will execute the `reBuild` function of the plugin, which will take care of resizing sections, updating the inner containers and scroll all the sections and slides of your site to fit the new position.

Firing this hundreds of times can cause some problems in slow computers and will slow down the page.